# Querying map with hibernate, jpql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, jpql

I was wondering i had the following error while querying a map with hibernate jpql:

**Hibernate version**
4.1.5

```
/** Map */
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Credential.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Musician, EMusicGroupCredential> members;
```

## Test Query 1

```
`1. select o from Group o join o.members member where key(member).address.country = :country;
```

## Test Query 2

```
2. select o from Group o join o.members member where key(member.address.country) = :country;
```

With both test i'm following on de-referenced error. First one saying i cannot de-reference key attribut. Second saying that i cannot dereference scalar collection element: address.

I believe this is a Hibernate, jpql, jpa limitation, but i would like to have some other point of view on this problem.

Regards.